# Removing failed drive from Storage Pool in Server 2016

Tags: windows, powershell, storage

Following instructions found [here](https://hodgkins.io/replace-failed-disk-in-storage-spaces-pool-with-powershell) and [here](https://www.mmo-champion.com/threads/1450727-Guide-How-to-remove-a-Physical-Disk-from-Windows-Storage-Spaces-WITH-Parity), I've been trying to replace a failing drive in a Windows Storage Pool. Here are the steps I'm taking after physically replacing the drive.

When running `Get-PhysicalDisk`, I see:

```
FriendlyName           SerialNumber    CanPool OperationalStatus  HealthStatus Usage            Size
------------           ------------    ------- -----------------  ------------ -----            ----
WDC WD1003FBYX-01Y7B1  WD-WCAW36848546 False   OK                 Healthy      Auto-Select 931.51 GB
WDC WD4000F9MZ-76NVPL0 WD-WCC131932768 False   OK                 Healthy      Auto-Select   3.64 TB
Generic Physical Disk                  False   Lost Communication Warning      Auto-Select   3.64 TB
WDC WD1003FBYX-01Y7B1  WD-WCAW36848210 False   OK                 Healthy      Auto-Select 931.51 GB
WDC WD4000F9MZ-76NVPL0 WD-WCC131962755 False   OK                 Healthy      Auto-Select   3.64 TB
WDC WD4000F9MZ-76NVPL0 WD-WCC131965649 False   OK                 Healthy      Auto-Select   3.64 TB
WDC WD4000F9YZ-09N20L0 WD-WCC130974882 False   OK                 Healthy      Auto-Select   3.64 TB
```

It's clear which one is the bad drive. So, I'm setting the bad disk to a variable,
`$badDisk = Get-PhysicalDisk | Where-Object { $_.OperationalStatus -eq 'Lost Communication' }`

And then retire it.

`$badDisk | Set-PhysicalDisk -Usage Retired`

From there, I try to remove the disk.

`Remove-PhysicalDisk -PhysicalDisks $badDisk -StoragePoolName DataStore1`

```
Remove-PhysicalDisk : The requested object could not be found.
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-PhysicalDisk -PhysicalDisks $badDisk -StoragePoolName Data ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (PS_StorageCmdlets:ROOT/Microsoft/..._StorageCmdlets) [Remove-PhysicalDi
sk], CimException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MI RESULT 6,Remove-PhysicalDisk
```

Oh...kay?

Add in the replacement disk first, then?

`$replacementDisk = Get-PhysicalDisk –FriendlyName 'WDC WD4000F9YZ-09N20L0'`

`Add-PhysicalDisk –PhysicalDisks $replacementDisk –StoragePoolFriendlyName DataStore1`

```
Add-PhysicalDisk : The requested object could not be found.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-PhysicalDisk –PhysicalDisks $replacementDisk –StoragePoolFriendly ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (PS_StorageCmdlets:ROOT/Microsoft/..._StorageCmdlets) [Add-PhysicalDisk]
, CimException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MI RESULT 6,Add-PhysicalDisk
```

What the hell am I doing wrong? I know I don't know Powershell as well as I'd like but... Everything here seems fairly straightforward.

Comment: Silly question here, but are you sure your StoragePoolFriendlyName is correct and accessible?  If you're not tied to PowerShell, have you tried using the Server Manager UI?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you solved it, but I had exactly the same issue and just found here the solution:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a7cdd6ce-db9c-47f8-b366-8d0b437a6bb8/removephysicaldisk-fails-with-failover-clustering-and-storage-spaces-in-windows-server-2016?forum=winserverfiles

I used these 4 lines (just replace the 2 parameters that include 'YourXxxXxx'):

```
$Clustername = "YourClusterName"
Get-CimInstance -Namespace root\mscluster -ComputerName $ClusterName -ClassName MScluster_ClusterService | Invoke-CimMethod -Name EnableHealth
Remove-PhysicalDisk -PhysicalDisks (Get-PhysicalDisk | ? OperationalStatus -eq ‘Lost Communication’) -StoragePoolFriendlyName YourStoragePoolName
Get-CimInstance -Namespace root\mscluster -ComputerName $ClusterName -ClassName MScluster_ClusterService | Invoke-CimMethod -Name DisableHealth
```